# Epicor 10 How to store data between BPM pre and post processing?

Tags: c#, business-process-management, epicorerp

I'm tying to migrate an Epicor V9 system with Progress/ABL code to v10 with C# code. I've got most of it done but I need a way to keep data between a BPMs pre and post processing. The comments in the original ABL code state:

> Description : This function stores data from a BPM pre processing action, it does this by using a private-data (storage attribute) on the calling program...
>      this remains in scope during both the BPM pre and BPM post forward to procedure calls

The Epicor v9 system was set up such that the Quote form calls the BPM pre/post processing in a .p file. The .p file in turned call the code I am trying to migrate in a .i file. It looks to be a simple stack or array of strings.

What would be used in Epicor 10 to persist data between pre/post BPM processing like the .i code did in V9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CallContext.Properties for this.

In E10.0 the CallContext.Properties was of type Epicor.Utilities.PropertyBag, and items would be accessed as below:

```
//Add
CallContext.Properties.Add("LineRef", LineRef);
// Get
var LineRef = (string)CallContext.Properties["LineRef"];
// Remove
CallContext.Properties.Remove("LineRef");
```

E10.1 CallContext.Properties is now of type System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurentDictionary, which is a .Net built in type and much better documented. However the methods to add and remove entries from it have changes as below:

```
//Add
bool added = CallContext.Properties.TryAdd("LineRef", LineRef);
// Get
var LineRef = (string)CallContext.Properties["LineRef"];  //Note: Do not use .ToString() this converts instead of unboxing.
// Remove
object dummy;
bool foundAndRemoved = CallContext.Properties.TryRemove("LineRef", out dummy);
```

To use this your class needs to inherit from ContextBoundBase and implement the only the context bound constructor or you will get `'Ice.ContextBoundBase<Erp.ErpContext>.ContextBoundBase()' is obsolete: 'Use the constructor that takes a data context'`

```
public partial class MyInvokeExternalMethodThing : ContextBoundBase<ErpContext>
{
    public MyInvokeExternalMethodThing(ErpContext ctx) : base(ctx)
    {

    }
```

In E10.1 you can put any kind of object into this, so if you have an array of strings you don't need to use the old trick of tilde~separated~values.

Comment: Do you know how to use CurrentCallContext.CurrentUser? I have a pre-processing BPM , on the update method to store the user that made the update. Currently, it doesn't, I don't know why, it just doesn't insert the data. I looked at Epicor documentation and had no luck. I'm using E10

Comment: You need to ask this as a separate question, rather than adding it as a comment to this answer. Just remember to tag it with [epicorerp] and mention the version of Epicor ERP you are using in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about using .i files from E9 but I do know how to persist data between pre and post method directives in E10.  Hopefully this helps.

There are a couple of different ways to do this.  If when creating the pre-process bpm you chose the "Execute Custom Code" option.  You can do it directly in your code using callContextBpmData.  Almost all of the field names are similar to that of the user fields that E9 used (i.e. Number01, Chracter01, Date01).

In your code if you are setting text you could simply type:

```
callContextBpmData.Character01 = "some text";
```

Alternatively you could set it directly in the bpm designer without any code.  In the designer left window pane, scroll all the way to the bottom, you should see something called "Set BPM Data Field".  Drag it into the design area.  After dragging it into the designer area you should see the option to set a field and its value in the bottom window pane.  Select the field, then when you select "value" you are taken to a window similar to baq calculated field designer.  You can use static data or use the data in the business object to calculate a value.

Comment: I can't get the "callContextBpmData" to be recognized by Visual Studio. Do you have any idea what reference I need to add? Thanks!

Comment: I know callContextBpmData is of type Ice.Tablesets.BpmDataRow and I think you get access to the local reference through Epicor.Customization.BPM.  However I'm not positive about that.  If you pull all of the associated bpm files directly from the server into visual studio it seems to recognize it automatically.